# function isPrimeNumber in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a number is a prime number by typing it in a box, then click on a button and get the value is prime number or is not a prime number. I have the following code, but for some reason I can't figure it out why it is not working - I get the value is prime number for any number I tried.

```js
function isPrimeNumber() {
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      document.getElementById("result").value = "not a prime number";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = "prime number";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="n">
    <input type="button" value="Check if I am prime!" onclick="isPrimeNumber();">
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </p>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The assignment after the loop will happen regardless of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you've found a prime number, you currently continue the loop. What you want to do is break it and/or return the result like so:

```js
function isPrimeNumber() {
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      document.getElementById("result").value = "not a prime number";
      return true;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = "prime number";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="n">
    <input type="button" value="Check if I am prime!" onclick="isPrimeNumber();">
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `document.getElementById("result").value="prime number";` you are always setting the result as `prime number`. You need to make it conditional. Try following

```js
function isPrimeNumber() {
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  var isPrime = true;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = isPrime ? "prime number" : "not a prime number";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="n">
    <input type="button" value="Check if I am prime!" onclick="isPrimeNumber();">
    <input type="text" id="result">
  </p>
</form>
```